# Ruby on Rails: adding css dynamically when rendering different partials

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm rendering different views through ajax, and I was wondering how do I manage css. I have two buttons, where I want to highlight the active button.

**index.haml**

```
#button-group
  = link_to grid_view_path, class: "col-xs-3", remote: true do
    %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-th
  = link_to flat_view_path, class: "col-xs-3", remote: true do
    %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-th-list

#view-container
  = render "grid_view"
```

**grid_view.js.erb**

```
$('#view-container').html("<%= j render :partial => 'grid_view' %>");
```

**flat_view.js.erb**

```
$('#view-container').html("<%= j render :partial => 'flat_view' %>");
```

**welcome_controller.rb**

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html    
      format.js
    end    
  end

  def flat_view
  end

  def grid_view
  end

end
```

At initial page load, the index page shows the **grid_view** partial, then user can click on the buttons, and it will display either display the flat view or grid view. Currently, the glyphicon both is highlighted blue (assuming its default). I would probably want to add a class to the *non-active* button, and keep the blue on the one that is *active*. What would be the best way to do this? Or if there's another method that I should do, please help.

Comment: if there's no significant difference between two views ie html layout then I think adding a class is your best option

Comment: @kasperite how would I add the class? And the two views are different, one is a grid layout and the other is a flat layout. And I'm only referring to the buttons that needs to be added with a active/non-active class, i wouldn't need to add any classes to the html layouts

Answer (score 1):

I think you can directly use bootstrap tabs feature.

Just in tab-content part place the render partial, and the corresponding tab will get highlighted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In the js.erb files:

`$('#button_to_acc_class_to').addClass('non-active');`

Although you may actually want to make a JS function like `initializeView(view)` with the above code in it, along with everything else that needs to change when the view changes, and call it from your js.erb files. I would take this approach, as you probably will add a number of behaviors when a view changes, by the time you are done.